# Python mongodb sample app

Tags: python, mongodb

I am thinking of using mongodb for a custom application. I am new to mongodb, and I am looking for a sample application (minimal, but a little bit more useful than `hello world`), which shows how a small but useful application (e.g. a blog application), can be written using Python and mongodb.

Such a (small but useful) application will help me understand how to develop my application; particular how to go from the RDBMS way of thinking to the NoSQL mindset. However despite searching online for a while, I have not come accross such an example. Is anyone of such a "useful" or "realworld" sample app?

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to Tornado](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449309070) actually has a section on building a blog using Tornado as the web-server and MongoDB as the database.  The code for the book is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Introduction-to-Tornado/Introduction-to-Tornado) as well if you want to read through it to get an understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please see for https://github.com/mr0re1/NCR at Application/application/mongoloid.py.
There is simple code which connects to MongoDB, and pass simple operations.

```
connection = pymongo.Connection(settings.MONGOLOID['host'], settings.MONGOLOID['port'])
db = connection[settings.MONGOLOID['database']]
```

Where descriptions of "host", "port" and "database" are in settings.py.

All operations are very simple, like this `db['lexemes'].find(request)`, where "lexemes" is a collection name, and "request" is dictionary.